# Excel VBA - When opening Hyperlink in chrome, my current sign-on to Lightspeed is Invalid?

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, lightspeed

I have been building a rather large Excel program for adding and editing Tags in lightspeed Retail POS since they have a rather weak interface.

At times, it would be nice to have a command button to open the product page in Lightspeed to double check a detail.  I added a command button to my form and attached the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://us.merchantos.com/?name=item.views.item&form_name=view&id=" & Cells(2,1) & "&tab=details"
```

Cells(2,1) contains the item ID

If I open a tab and paste the contents of that address link, the item detail page opens perfectly.

If I click the command Button, The tab opens in Chrome, but it assumes I am not logged in and asks for a username and password.  Once supplied, I end up on the home page and not the item detail page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using chrome incognito? Is chrome set up to clear browsing history / cookies when windows are closed? Put in a different way, when you manually open a new **window** manually do you have to always sign in or does it remember that you were signed in before?

Comment: Just a regular chrome session, and I already have multiple tabs open with Lightspeed.  Generally once one tab is signed into our account, you can have as many tabs open as you want, and each one has you logged in automatically.  And if I open a blank tab and paste the link from excel into the address bar, it opens fine.

Comment: It might then be the case that chrome is sending a flag that the request was automated and as a security measure lightspeed asks for a re-login.

Answer (score 0):

There was a security Setting for Chrome which throws the login issue.

The solution was to open the link using Shell

```
chromeFileLocation = """C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
Shell (chromeFileLocation & "-url " & Link)
```

This bypasses the security and opens the link on a new Tab.